# DTS Send Email Task sends email twice

Tags: ssis, dts

I have a Send Email Task in my DTS Package OnPostExecute event. It sends email to the developers after this package gets executed. It works but the problem is it sends the same email twice. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixd it. Instead of having the Send Email Task in the package I placed it in the Data Flow Task. Now it's sending things once.

Thanks!

Ryan

Comment: And you can place it at the end of the control flow as well. It will work fine.